# Scala class inheriting from a Java generic class

Tags: java, scala, inheritance

I am trying to write a Hadoop mapper class in Scala. As a starting point, I have taken a Java example from the book "Hadoop: the Definitive Guide" and tried to port it to Scala.

The original Java class extends `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper`:

```
public class MaxTemperatureMapper
    extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
```

and overrides the method

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

This methods gets called and works properly (I tested using a unit test and then run it with yarn).

My attempt at a Scala port is:

```
class MaxTemperatureMapperS extends Mapper[LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable]
```

and then the method

```
@throws(classOf[IOException])
@throws(classOf[InterruptedException])
override def map(key: LongWritable, value: Text, context: Context): Unit = 
{
    ...
}
```

but the Scala compiler issues an error:

```
error: method map overrides nothing.
```

So I thought the two methods had the same signature in Scala and Java, but apparently I am missing something. Can you give me some hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes the best way to do this is by letting your IDE work for you:

```
class Test extends Mapper[LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable] {
  override def map(key: LongWritable, value: Text, context: Mapper[LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable]#Context): Unit = ???
}
```

In this case the problem is that the definition of the class Context "lives" inside the class `Mapper` so you need to use the # syntax

Comment: So the `Context` that was found by the compiler was probably some other class that was in scope! It makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It works now. I have ported the whole Hadoop example application from Java to Scala and it runs without a glitch. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For reference providing code for  overriding both map and reduce method in Mapper and Reducer class respectively in scala

Mapper Example :

```scala
class MaxTemperatureMapper extends Mapper[LongWritable, Text, AvroKey[Integer], AvroValue[GenericRecord]] {

  val parser = new NcdcRecordParser()
  val record = new GenericData.Record(AvroSchema.SCHEMA)

  @throws(classOf[IOException])
  @throws(classOf[InterruptedException])
  override def map(key: LongWritable, value: Text, context:Mapper[LongWritable, Text, AvroKey[Integer], AvroValue[GenericRecord]]#Context) = {
```

Reducer Example :

```scala
class MaxTemperatureReducer extends  Reducer[AvroKey[Integer],AvroValue[GenericRecord],AvroKey[GenericRecord],NullWritable]{

  @throws(classOf[IOException])
  @throws(classOf[InterruptedException])
  override def reduce(key:AvroKey[Integer],values:java.lang.Iterable[AvroValue[GenericRecord]],
      context:Reducer[AvroKey[Integer],AvroValue[GenericRecord],AvroKey[GenericRecord],NullWritable]#Context) = {
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edited as required.Thanks.